# How to show the text with Line Breaks

Tags: html, angularjs

[image]

I need to display the text with the line breaks, this is the script

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
    app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
        console.log('Controller is executed');
        $scope.btnClick = function () {
            console.log($scope.desc);
        }
        $scope.ShowData = function () {
            $scope.text = $scope.desc;
        }
    });
</script>
```

And this is the html code

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
<form>
    <textarea ng-model="desc" cols="105" rows="15"></textarea>
    <button ng-click="btnClick()">Submit</button>
    <button ng-click="ShowData()">Show</button>
</form>
<div ng-bind="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try render text inside `<pre></pre>` tag instead of `<div>`.
Or use `style="white-space:pre-wrap;"` on your div.

Comment: [The Preformatted Text element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre), or just `<pre>` for friends, documentation.

Comment: I'm using `style="white-space:pre-wrap;"`.

Answer (score 11):

Use the right CSS. The default style of the `pre` tag preserves line breaks:

```
<pre>{{text}}</pre>
```

or you can use CSS ([white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)):

```
div {
    white-space: pre; /* or pre-wrap or pre-line */
    /* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add this to your styles, this works for me

```css
white-space: pre-wrap
```

**HTML**

```html
<p class="text-style">{{product?.description}}</p>
```

**CSS**

```css
.text-style {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

By this text in `<textarea>`can be display as it's in there with spaces and line brakes

Comment: But there is a problem with "pre" that it adds a lot of white spaces in the beginning

Answer (score 3):

Add a `pre` tag, **`<pre></pre>`**, where you are displaying text.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
<body ng-app="">

<p>Write something with breaks and check:</p>

<textarea ng-model="myTextarea"></textarea>

<p>The content of the textarea is;</p>
<pre><span>{{myTextarea}}</span></pre>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above code**

[Here is a working **DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/dmPOvhOU0d5MLYciplGi?p=preview)

Comment: h1 automatically puts the text on next line unless we have changed its behaviour through css code. I think you should use <span> tag in your example instead of <h1>

Comment: I don't think `h1` automatically adds the new line, you can check my example link, by removing the `pre` tag.

Comment: h1 does add new line automatically. For example. https://jsfiddle.net/mkau1uaL/ . Actually what I am saying is, that you should use <span> tag in your example instead of h1. Otherwise the OP might think that h1 puts the text on same line.

Comment: @GiulioBambini, you misunderstood the question, he is not talking about `h1` or `span`.  he is talking about text inside the text area, anyhow I changed `h1` to `span` to avoid this confusion. :)

Comment: I am not saying your answer is wrong or right. Just pointed out a room for improvement in your answer. Cheers :)

Comment: yes @GiulioBambini, I understood that and updated. Thnx. :)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
    app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
        console.log('Controller is executed');
        $scope.btnClick = function () {
            console.log($scope.desc);
        }
        $scope.ShowData = function () {
            $scope.text = $scope.desc.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
        }
    });
</script>
```

line breaks (\n\r?) are not the same as HTML < br /> tags

Answer (score 0):

**Add style on your css**

```
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <form>
        <textarea ng-model="desc" cols="105" rows="15"></textarea>
        <button ng-click="btnClick()">Submit</button>
        <button ng-click="ShowData()">Show</button>
    </form>
    <div ng-bind="text" class="line-break"></div>

<style>
    .line-break {
    width: 90px; //Give some width accoring you
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }
 </style>
```